# Add six months in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to get the month, six months out from the current date.

I've tried using:

`date('d', strtotime('+6 month', time()));`

But it doesn't seem to work, always returns `01`.  Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, `strtotime()` uses the current time by default if you omit the second parameter. Also, I don’t think `strtotime()` will compute months as it isn’t an absolute time period, e.g. the number of days differ on a month-to-month basis.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I find working with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) much easier to use:

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->modify('+6 months');
echo $datetime->format('d');
```

or

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo $datetime->format('d');
```

or in PHP version 5.4+

```
echo (new \DateTime())->add(new \DateInterval('P6M'))->format('d');
```

Answer (score 4):

If you still wanted to use strtotime and the date function as opposed to a DateTime() object, the following would work:

```
date('d', strtotime('+6 months'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `time()` to strtotime, as it is the default.

Apart from that, your approach is correct - except that you take `date('d')` (which is putting out the day) and not `date('m')` for the month, so `echo date('m', strtotime('+6 month'));` should do.

Nevertheless, I would recommend using the `DateTime` way, which John stated. `DateTime` has several advantages over the "old" date functions, for example they don't stop working when the seconds since the UNIX big bang don't fit into an 32bit integer any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateTime` class in conjunction with the `DateInterval` class:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));

echo $date->format('d M Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 month' , strtotime(date("2022-07-05"))));
```

Answer:
2023-01-05